# PHP preg_match regular expression

Tags: php, preg-match

```
$var = '<lang test=<php>string</php>><lang test2=before<php>inside</php>>'.
       '<lang test3=THIRD_WITHOUT_PHP_TAGS><lang test4>';
if (preg_match_all('#<lang (.*?)>#', $var, $gg))
{
    var_dump($gg[1]);
}
```

I get the dump:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "test=<php"
  [1]=>
  string(16) "test2=before<php"
}
```

But I want to get :

```
test=<php>string</php>
```

and

```
test2=before<php>inside</php>
```

and

```
test3=THIRD_WITHOUT_PHP_TAGS
```

and

```
test4
```

How to do it?

**EDIT:
I CHANGE THE $var AND ADD third expression**

**EDIT 2:
ADEED the fourth expression without "="**

Comment: Is `</php>` always at the end (`</php>>`) ?

Comment: you could use `$var = '<lang test=[php]string[/php]><lang test2=before[php]inside[/php]>';
` and you whont need to modify you're regexp , or you could skip the first two ocurences of '>' but then what if you pass `$var = '<lang test=some other test>` without any <php> tags ? somebody else better than me will figure out an answer without the need to change the php tags

Comment: @Jan Hančič, not always. This may not be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be

```
#<lang (\w+=[^<]*(<[^>]+>)?[^<]+(?(2)</[^>]+>))>#
```

The Regex checks if a tag is matched and only then checks for ending tag.

If you want to catch also the fourth argument, you need to use

```
#<lang (\w+(=[^<]*(<[^>]+>)?[^<]+(?(3)</[^>]+>))?)>#
```

Comment: EDIT: I CHANGE THE $var AND ADD third expression

Comment: Should work aswell. I just tried it. It matches the first two and doesn't get the third lang.

Comment: Thank you.. but I have a problem.. <lang test4> .... test4 It is necessary that "test4" too was in the array.. For your tests: $var = '<lang test=<php>string</php>><lang test2=before<php>inside</php>><lang test3=int><lang test4>';

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = '<lang test=<php>string</php>><lang test2=before<php>inside</php>>';
if (preg_match_all('#<lang (.*>)>#U', $var, $gg))
{
    var_dump($gg[1]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do it this way:

```
preg_match("/<lang (.*)>/i", $var, $gg)
```

Comment: This would completly match `<lang test=<php>string</php>><lang test2=before<php>inside</php>><lang test3=THIRD_WITHOUT_PHP_TAGS>`

Comment: @ S-Buzz but he says he wants to get all so why the downrep?

Comment: He wants to get all three ones as a single match. Your regex matches the whole string